# How to partially pivot a table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not sure if "pivot" is the right term for this, but I have something like

| ID | type | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1-2-2020 |
| 123 | B | 1-7-2020 |
| 123 | C | 1-14-2020 |
| 456 | A | 5-18-2019 |
| 456 | B | 5-30-2019 |
| 789 | A | 8-7-2021 |
| 789 | B | 8-16-2021 |
| 789 | C | 8-23-2021 |
| 789 | D | 8-30-2021 |

And I want to transform it into something like:

| ID | type_1 | date_1 | type_2 | date_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | 1-2-2020 | B | 1-7-2020 |
| 123 | B | 1-7-2020 | C | 1-14-2020 |
| 456 | A | 5-18-2019 | B | 5-30-2019 |
| 789 | A | 8-7-2021 | B | 8-16-2021 |
| 789 | B | 8-16-2021 | C | 8-23-2021 |
| 789 | C | 8-23-2021 | D | 8-30-2021 |

So that they types are paired and every row has exactly two types and dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
new_df = pd.concat([
    df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: g.head(g.shape[0] - 1)).reset_index(drop=True),
    df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g: g.tail(g.shape[0] - 1)).reset_index(drop=True).drop('ID', axis=1)
], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
    ID type       date type       date
0  123    A   1-2-2020    B   1-7-2020
1  123    B   1-7-2020    C  1-14-2020
2  456    A  5-18-2019    B  5-30-2019
3  789    A   8-7-2021    B  8-16-2021
4  789    B  8-16-2021    C  8-23-2021
5  789    C  8-23-2021    D  8-30-2021
```

More compact version:

```
new_df = pd.concat([df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g:g.head(g.shape[0]-1)).reset_index(drop=True),df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda g:g.tail(g.shape[0]-1)).reset_index(drop=True).drop('ID', axis=1)],axis=1)
```